# JavaScript Longest common subsequence

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops

I have an algorithm that must return the result as follow:

```
/*
"ABAZDC", "BACBAD" => ABAD
"AGGTAB", "GXTXAYB" => GTAB
"aaaa", "aa" => "aa"
"", "..." => ""
"ABBA", "ABCABA" => "ABBA"
*/
```

The code that I developed didn't return these results. How can I solve it?

```
console.log(solution('ABAZDC', 'BACBAD')) 

function solution(str1, str2) {
  str1 = str1.split('')
  str2 = str2.split('')  
  
  const output = []
 
  for(let i = str1.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {   
    for(let j = str2.length -1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if( str2[j] === str1[i] ) {
        output.push(str2[j]) 
        break
      }      
    } 
    
  }
  
  return output.reverse().join('')
 
}
```

**NOTE:**

Here's a solution on youtube. But for me, this solution is complicated for those who are not familiar with this problem. I'd like to see a simpler solution for now. It would be a solution that does NOT contain recursive functions or memoization.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10WnvBk9sZc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: Here is the solution, https://youtu.be/10WnvBk9sZc

Comment: @Sanjeetkumar I had seen this video before, but his solution is very complicated for me yet. I would like to see a more simply solution like an iterative solution. When I will get it, I will try to understand the advanced ways like: recursives, memoization and others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Here you go !**
You need to create matrix with "A.length + 1" rows and "B.length + 1" columns (elements in 0th index are all 0s) and the rightest lowest number in your matrix will be your answer. In this example -

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2
0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3

function longestCommonSubsequence(a, b) {
    const matrix = Array(a.length + 1).fill().map(() => Array(b.length + 1).fill(0));
    for(let i = 1; i < a.length + 1; i++) {
        for(let j = 1; j < b.length + 1; j++) {
            if(a[i-1] === b[j-1]) {
                matrix[i][j] = 1 + matrix[i-1][j-1];
            } else {
                matrix[i][j] = Math.max(matrix[i-1][j], matrix[i][j-1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix[a.length][b.length];
}

let a = [2,3,4];
let b = [2,3,7,8,4];

console.log(longestCommonSubsequence(a,b));
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to watch this video first, the solution is very well explained in it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASoaQq66foQ

The code is returning the max length of the string, you can modify it in order to serve your purpose.

```
function longestCommonSubsequence(s1, s2) {
  // string to array
  const arr1 = [...s1]
  const arr2 = [...s2]

  // define n x m sized array filled with 0's
  let matrix = [...Array(arr1.length+1)].map(e => Array(arr2.length+1).fill(0))

  // fill the matrix
  for(let i = 1; i <= arr1.length; i++) {
      for(let j = 1; j <= arr2.length; j++) {
          if(arr1[i-1] == arr2[j-1]) { matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j] + 1}
          else matrix[i][j] = Math.max(matrix[i-1][j], matrix[i][j-1])
      }
  }

  // return the max which is at the right bottom corner of the matrix
  return matrix[matrix.length-1][matrix[0].length-1]
}
```

Comment: great. just wanted to add it works for non-repeated characters in sequence

Answer (score 1):

The function will return the longest substring for a given two-strings.

```
function longestCommonSubstring(str1, str2) {

    if (str1 === str2) return str2;
    if (!str2.split('').some(ele => str1.includes(ele))) return '';
    let commonSubStr = '';
    let storage = [];
    const strLength = str2.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {

        let ind = str1.indexOf(str2[i]);
        if (ind === -1) continue;

        for (let j = i, k = ind; j < strLength; j++, k++) {
            if (str2[j] === str1[k])
                commonSubStr += str2[j];
            else {
                storage.push(commonSubStr);
                commonSubStr = '';
            }
        }
        storage.push(commonSubStr);
        commonSubStr = '';
    }

    return storage.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0].length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A really good explanation on how to find the LCS between two strings can be found at  https://alfedenzo.livejournal.com/170301.html.  I used that article in my javascript solution to PatienceDiff, found at https://github.com/jonTrent/PatienceDiff.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// the shortest way
function lcs(
s1, s2, alp=2, accumulator = ''
){
  for( let a in s1 ){
    for( let b=a-alp; b<a+alp; b++ ){
      accumulator += ( s2[b] === s1[a] && a-b < alp && b-a < alp ) ? s1[a]:"";
    }
  }
  return accumulator;
}
console.log(
lcs("ABAZDC", "BACBAD") +'\n'+ 
lcs("AGGTAB", "GXTXAYB")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const subsequence = (s1,s2) => {    
const output = []    
let string1= [...s1];    
let string2 = [...s2];    
for(let i =0;i<=string1.length-1;i++){
          for(let j =0;j<=string2.length-1;j++){
              if(string1[i]===string2[j]){
                    output.push(string2[j]) 
                break;
              }
          }    
}   
return output.join('') } 
console.log(subsequence("ABAZDC", "BACBAD"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You just to need to add a check if thats matching char is already added or not using like `! output.contains(str2[j] )` or below

```
    function solution(str1, str2) {
  str1 = str1.split('')
  str2 = str2.split('')  

  const output = []

  for(let i = str1.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {   
    for(let j = str2.length -1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if( str2[j] === str1[i]
          ) {
          str2.replace(str2[j], "" ) ;
        output.push(str2[j]) 
        break
      }      
    } 

  }
```

Comment: Error message: str2.replaceAll is not a function

Comment: Use replace instead of replaceAll

Comment: i changed it but it continues not working, It is showing the same error again

Comment: It’s good for you to have your solution tested before publishing